# libGDX TiledMapRenderer not drawing

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have problems with `TiledMapRenderer`. I have made a tmx map with 4 tile objects and 1 tile 64x64 each tile in the map with `Tiled Map Editor`. But I can't figure out what I have missed. There is nothing on the screen. The map and tile set are in assets folder. I have google a lot, copy pasted code from tutorials and `GDX` `TiledMap` test but see nothing on my `Alcatel One Touch Pixi 4007d` `GLES 2.0` ready phone except fps counter and camera position. What have I missed? May be the answers will be helpful for other novice `libGDX` programmers.
I have checked the map in the debugger and all the variables were initialized, there also were a layer in the map.

Here is the code of the `Game` class

```
public class GameMain extends Game implements InputProcessor
{ 
private TiledMap map;
private TiledMapRenderer renderer;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private BitmapFont font;
private SpriteBatch batch;

Vector2 mPrevTouch;

@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, (w / h) * 10, 10);
    camera.update();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    font = new BitmapFont();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("test.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.55f, 0.55f, 0.55f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 10, 20);
    font.draw(batch, "Pos: " + camera.position.x + " " + camera.position.y, 20, 20);
    batch.end();        
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    map.dispose();
}    

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int arg2) {

    if (mPrevTouch == null)
        mPrevTouch = new Vector2(0, 0);
    else
        camera.translate(new Vector2(screenX - mPrevTouch.x, screenY - mPrevTouch.y));

    mPrevTouch.x = screenX;
    mPrevTouch.y = screenY;

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK, so I think you have problem with camera size or camera position. What is the size of your TMX map? + try to create camera this way:

```
    tiledMapCamera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Comment: Alon Zilberman, thank you man for the answer, nevertheless there was still nothing on the screen after camera code update, though it was something that made me keep digging. Finally, I have loaded a `Windows BMP` tileset and voila, it worked. Thus, there is something with `PNG` maps or `Tiled Map Editor 0.8`. Why is everything not so simple? I have also checked `TmxMapLoader` fields deeper in debugger and found that `pixmap` is null but the size fields are ok.

Comment: Check your tmx file (open with notepad) if pathes to tile sets in image source tag are ok. Also try to fill all map with some tiles, maybe you will see something and we will understand that it is camera zoom/position problem. It should be simple, you have some small bug which should be find.

Comment: Alon Zilberman, thanks a lot now I am so close to solution. I see there is something with the tmx map, I have just loaded png map with only tiles, no tile objects. I will post solution when I find one.

Comment: Alon Zilberman, Ok, finally it was mainly camera error why I didn't see my only one tile in the map. Second is that `TmxMapLoader` doesn't support `tile-object`. There is no such type. This type of objects is interpreted as `RectangleMapObject` and I have to draw it manually.